# How to remove classname using multiple classname in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just trying to manipulate the class name using offsetTop and ScrollY. I have multiple div with class name of flex. I just tying to add and remove the "slide" classname using conditional statement. I can add the "slide" classname while reaching offset boundary. But I can't remove the classname after exit the boundary. Please help me for this situation. I have attached the code below.

```js
function GetScroll() {
  let FlexPositions = document.querySelectorAll(".flex");
  let RemoveClass = document.querySelector("div");
  FlexPositions.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.offsetTop < window.scrollY + 300) {
      RemoveClass.classList.remove('slide')
      item.classList.add('slide');
    }
  })

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body onscroll="GetScroll()">
  <div class="flex">A</div>
  <div class="flex">B</div>
  <div class="flex">C</div>
  <div class="flex">D</div>
  <div class="flex">E</div>
  <div class="flex">F</div>
  <div class="flex">G</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I made you a [mcve]

Comment: `let RemoveClass = document.querySelector("div");` is the first div (and it works for that)

Comment: Yes I tried this way and its working for first div only. But I need to work for all div. Please help me

Comment: Just an FYI, in my experience in JS we want to save PascalCase for `class`es and use camelCasing for vars and functions.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I will add the 'slide' classname while scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code

You need to get the element with the slide class

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  let flexPositions = document.querySelectorAll(".flex");
  document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    flexPositions.forEach(item => {
      if (item.offsetTop < window.scrollY + 300) {
        document.querySelector("div.slide").classList.remove('slide')
        item.classList.add('slide');
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="flex slide">A</div>
<div class="flex">B</div>
<div class="flex">C</div>
<div class="flex">D</div>
<div class="flex">E</div>
<div class="flex">F</div>
<div class="flex">G</div>
```

Comment: Its working now thank you so mush @mplungjan

Comment: YW. I updated to cache the divs. No need to get them all the time